# Basic Vector field question about notation

Tags: electromagnetism, notation, vector-fields

I am taking my first class in electrodynamics and the problem I am working on has a notation I have never seen before

Consider a vector field of the form

$V= f(x)y + g(y)x$

Is this essentially the same thing as saying:

$V= f(x,y) = y\hat{x} + x\hat{y}$
?

Comment: No. It's not clear to me what your second equation really means. You have set a vector equal to a scalar equal to a vector times another vector from the way I'm reading it. What your first equation is saying is that you have a vector whose y component is dependent on its x coordinate and whose x component is dependent on its y coordinate.

Comment: I'm confused also.  Your first equations looks like a scalar to me.  Is it possible that it is the potential and you need to take the gradient to get the vector field?

Comment: I suppose that is possible but I'm really not sure.  the problem states that is how the field is defined.

Comment: @LewisMiller It looks like somebody has edited his post, as the first equation was not initially a scalar equation.

Comment: @Dargscisyhp The question has been re-formatted for readability but it is the same equation all along.

Comment: @user125621 Initially your first equation was a vector equation. It has lost that quality.